# Does the raw Python 'for' loop reduce training performance of TensorFlow

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, for-loop, bytecode

When having only 1 input (feed to placeholder), using tf.data.Dataset is optimal:

```
Data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((Inp,Exp));
Data = Data.repeat().shuffle(Dsize).batch(Bsize);

Steps  = 1000;
Epochs = round(Steps/(Dsize/Bsize));

...

Model.fit(Data, epochs=Epochs, steps_per_epoch=round(Dsize/Bsize));
```

However, when having multiple inputs (feed to multiple placeholders), Keras doesn't allow feeding mutliple Datasets, so the raw Python 'for' loop is used to feed batches:

```
Data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((Inp1,Inp2,Exp));
Data = Data.repeat().shuffle(Dsize).batch(Bsize);
Iter = iter(Data);

Steps = 1000;

...
for I in range(Steps):
  X1,X2,Y = next(Iter);
  Model.fit(x=[X1,X2], y=Y);
```

**Because Python is interpreter and runs on bytecode, the 'for' loop should be slow. I'm afraid that using the custom 'for' loop will reduce training performance. Is it true?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt the from_tensor_slices so that it stays a tuple of 2 elements, and where the first element is itself a tuple.

Working example:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


input_1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10,))
dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)(input_1)
input_2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10,))
dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)(input_2)
x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([dense_1, dense_2])
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)(x)

model = tf.keras.Model([input_1, input_2], y)
model.summary()

dataset_size = 16
batch_size = 4
input_1_values = np.random.random((dataset_size, 10))
input_2_values = np.random.random((dataset_size, 10))
output_values = np.random.random((dataset_size, 2))

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((input_1_values, input_1_values), output_values))
dataset = dataset.repeat().shuffle(buffer_size=4).batch(batch_size)

steps = 10
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy")
model.fit(dataset, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps)
```

An other option to merge dataset into a single one could also be to use the [zip method](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#zip)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it's not necessary to use 'for' loop. I can avoid using the 'for' loop by using Keras only, while I can still use multiple Xes, but no longer using tf.data.Dataset:

```
Steps  = 1000;
Epochs = round(Steps/(Dsize/Bsize)); 
Lline  = 10;
Lafte  = round(Epochs/Lline);
if Lafte==0: Lafte=1;

#Train: Loop
L = Model.evaluate(x=[Inp1,Inp2], y=Exp, steps=round(Dsize/Bsize), batch_size=Bsize, 
                   verbose=0);
print(f"Initavg batch loss: {L:.9f}");                   

Model.fit(x=[Inp1,Inp2], y=Exp, epochs=Epochs, batch_size=Bsize, shuffle=True, 
          verbose=0, callbacks=[callback()]);
```